# How to post form value with span tag in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form in which there are many span elements and every span element have their id's my span tag is working as a input text field for form now I want to send the span field value to my php file to insert in my db like in php `$_POST['fname']` this value we can get if we are using input type text but if it is a span how to do this?

My code is:

```
<form action="form_submit1" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
        <span class= "sexyform" id="6" name="fname" data-placeholder="Enter Your First Name"></span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can use ajax for doing so..

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `<span>`?

Comment: yes i have style the form in such a way like in the Google form input text look like

Answer (score -1):

You use ajax

```
$(document).on("click", ".sexyform", function () {
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "form_submit1",
    data:{fname:id},
    success: function (result) {
       your action after success
     },
  })
})
```

Comment: not working please help is there any way i can do with php?